# Calculation of joint PDF

Tags: random-variable, density-function, joint-distribution

we have the joint PDF of two RVs $X$ and $Y.$
we also have two RVs $U = f(X,Y)$ and $V = g(X,Y),$ where
$f$ and $g$ are two variable functions.
How can I calculate the joint PDF of $U$ and $V$?
for example: $U = X^2-Y^2$ and $V = XY.$

Comment: This is the kind of question where _reading your textbook_ to see what it says about solving such problems is more useful than asking on this forum. Heck. the book might even use $X^2+Y^2$ and $XY$ in its illustration of the method.

Comment: @DilipSarwate No, it's related to something else that requires this as one of its steps. and also the book does not mention anything about it and the functions are just my example nothing else. I just want to understand the process, so if I get anything like it, I am able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

To find the joint PDF of two random variables U and V that are functions of two other random variables X and Y, we can use the change of variables technique. In this example, we have $U = X^2 - Y^2$ and $V = XY$.

The first step is to find the inverse functions of $U$ and $V$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$. For $U = X^2 - Y^2$, we can solve for $X$ and $Y$ as follows:

$X = \sqrt(\frac{U + Y^2}{2})$,
$Y = \sqrt(\frac{Y^2 - U}{2})$

For $V$ = $XY$, we can solve for $X$ and $Y$ as follows:

$X = \frac{V}{Y}$,
$Y = \frac{V}{X}$

The next step is to compute the Jacobian determinant of the inverse transformation. The Jacobian determinant is given by:

$J = |\frac{\partial(X,Y)}{\partial(U,V)}| = \frac{1}{2XY}$

Using the inverse functions and the Jacobian determinant, we can write the joint PDF of $U$ and $V$ as:

$f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X,Y}(x(u,v), y(u,v))\times|J|$

where $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$ are the inverse functions of $U$ and $V$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$, and $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is the joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$. Substituting the inverse functions and the Jacobian determinant, we get:

$f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{XY}(\sqrt(\frac{u+v^2}{2v}), \sqrt(\frac{v^2-u}{2v}))\times 
 \frac{1}{2v^2}$

This is the joint PDF of U and V in terms of u and v.

Comment: Unfortunately, even in the simple example offered in the question the map $(X,Y)\to(U,V)$ is not invertible.  That's because whenever you can find $(X,Y)$ for which $(X^2-Y^2,XY)=(U,V),$ then $(-X,-Y)$ is also a solution. Moreover, even when an inverse exists finding it can be tricky, as attested by your circular equation $Y=\sqrt{(Y^2-U)/2},$ which is no solution at all! For some advice about this and related problems, please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=jacobian+joint+is%3Aanswer).

Comment: You are correct. In general, the transformation from $(X,Y)$ --> $(U,V)$ may not be invertible, and even when an inverse exists, it may be difficult to find explicitly. This is a common issue when dealing with transformations of random variables.
Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's more than just an "issue:" it means your answer here is incorrect.

Comment: It's disheartening to encounter rudeness on this platform. Each individual here possesses a unique level of expertise and experience. Respectful collaboration is key to maintaining a positive environment. Remember, not everyone possesses the same level of mastery as you do. Your expertise is valuable, and sharing it in a supportive manner can greatly contribute to the community's growth.
When you come across an answer you disagree with, consider offering your own perspective while remaining courteous. This approach helps foster a more inclusive and productive atmosphere for all.

Comment: I'm sorry, but calling out an answer as incorrect is not rude: it is critically important for all readers to be aware of wrong results.